# Comparing two NSDates gives back false positives

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

So I am trying to compare a bunch of dates from my Database (Strings, which I convert to NSdates) with the current date.

When I run the code for an example date: `2016-07-17 12:28:51 +0000` it gives back false positives for the day before (yesterday).

Console output:

```
Optional(2016-07-15 22:00:00 +0000)
DAY IN THE PAST
Optional(2016-07-15 22:00:00 +0000)
DAY IN THE PAST
Optional(2016-07-16 22:00:00 +0000)
SAME DAY
Optional(2016-07-16 22:00:00 +0000)
SAME DAY
Optional(2016-07-16 22:00:00 +0000)
SAME DAY
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong here. Code:

```
let dateToday = NSDate() // example: 2016-07-17 12:28:51 +0000
 print(dateToday)
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let openDB = realm.objects(Article)
        for item in openDB {
            let getItem = item.toDate
            let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(getItem!)

            let order = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().compareDate(dateToday, toDate: date!,
                toUnitGranularity: .Day)
            print(date) //example 2016-07-17 22:00:00 +0000
            switch order {
            case .OrderedDescending:
                print("DAY IN THE PAST")
            case .OrderedAscending:
                print("FUTURE DATE")
            case .OrderedSame:
                print("SAME DAY")
            }
```

Please note that I only need to check the dates itself, I don't care about the time (hours, minutes).

Comment: Not sure if this is important, but I'll just add this info: In general I changed the date of my device to the 17th for testing this. Maybe this causes some issues with the code?

Comment: Are you in the GMT+2 timezone? Then  `2016-07-16 22:00:00 +0000` is `2016-07-17 00:00:00 +0200` according to your timezone and on the same day as the given date.

Comment: @MartinR I think I am indeed in a GMT +02:00 time (Belgium) since it is summer time. So It doesn't matter that my code ignores the hours and minutes? because of the 22, and my 2+ GMT it changes the date? 
How do I fix it manually? I never added the 22:00:00 in my code, it just seems to happen when converting to dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: `compareDate()` compares to the calendar's timezone, and that is your local timezone by default. On the other hand, NSDate itself is just an absolute point in time and has no knowledge of a timezone. Its *description* method prints the date in UTC. Which means that everything is OK. – If you search for "NSDate wrong by some hours" or "NSDateFormatter dateFromString wrong" then you should find many similar questions with answers.

Comment: @MartinR still searching, haven't found anything good until now, since the dates from the database are '2016-07-17' (string, so no hours/minutes), the 22h is added by NSDateFormatter itself. If I add the GMT thing, it shows 00:00 at the hours and minutes, but the day is wrong (it's the next day).

Comment: Your post is confusing. You say you are comparing dates against "the day before." I assume that you mean "the day before today," but that reference will only be meaningful for today, 15 July 2016, and it also doesn't tell us the specific time you are comparing against. You should really write your question as comparing your test dates against a fixed date in GMT so people can make sense of it 3 months (or 3 years) from now.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what result you need, and then code for that.

`NSDate` objects encode moments in time, anywhere on the planet. Internally they use GMT as their time base, but that is an implementation detail.

If you want to compare 2 dates to see if they fall on the same day you need to specify the time zone to use for the comparison. If I compare 11:02 PM and 12:02 PM in your time zone, GMT+2, those 2 dates fall on different days.

However, those times are 9:02 PM and 10:02 PM in GMT, and fall on the same day in GMT.

If you want to know if the dates are the same date in GMT then you need to create a gregorian calendar object and set it's time zone to GMT.